# Screen is flashing on and off when locked

Tags: windows-10, display

On my Windows 10 desktop, my screen sometimes flashes on and off when the computer is locked. This seems to in some way be tied to whether the room (LED) lights are on, and I have a webcam, but I don't see any sort of "ambient light" control in my settings. [Here's a video of what happens;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO4tL.jpg) as you can see, there's a white flash in the middle of the monitor as the screen flickers off. I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing it, but I would like to somehow make it stop.

My graphics card is an Nvidia GTX 1070 Ti, the display is an Acer XB240H, and the connection is DisplayPort with G-Sync. The Nvidia driver is up-to-date.

Comment: Are you using an HDMI cable to connect the monitor to your computer by any chance?

Comment: @MrEthernet No, it's DisplayPort.

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried updating your graphics card drivers? Also what's the model of the monitor?

Comment: @MrEthernet Yes, drivers are up-to-date. If it matters, this is an Nvidia card and the display is G-Sync. Monitor is an Acer XB240H; I've edited that into the question.